# Sum of all Moments around an axis as a nonzero number in Statics

Tags: torque, statics, equilibrium

Good time of day, everyone!

Here's one thing I can't quite grasp on. So given a Statics problem, I have:

$ΣM_x = 159 \;\mathrm{N\cdot m} ≠ 0$; (Sum of all moments around x-axis equals 150 N•m)

Now, how is this possible in a Statics problem? Is the object not in rotational equilibrium then and, more over, has angular acceleration? Which is not quite possible in the problem. There's definitely something I am not understanding properly.

**Sketch of the problem**:
[image]

Tension in cable BC is: **26.5 lb**

**F** here has a magnitude of: **53 lb**

Comment: You are totally right. This thing's rotation is accelerating. This is not a situation of statics.

Comment: Well, I have a metal L-shaped bar that is connected to a wall at one end, and is suspended by a cable at the other end. So basically what's going on is that the object might not rotate due to suspension but still have angular acceleration?

Comment: Can you show the sketch? If the bar is not moving (static) then the sum of torques *must* be zero. Maybe you have forgotten to include a torque in your calculation?

Comment: Added it to the first post!

Comment: Okay, so sum of all moments around x-axis in this case will be: `- (53 lb) x 6 ft + (26.5 lb) x 6 ft`  The weird part is that even the system that checks the answers, says that sum of Mx = 159 lb*ft How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the sketch doesn't show all forces acting on the bar. (*My guess is that this is a question concerning only rotation about the y-axis*)

There must be forces at point A as well. The bar seems fixed at this point so that a torque will appear here to balance the others in order to keep no rotation.

The torque 159 Nm comes from force $F$ and force along $BC$, and this means that the torque at A must hold back with this value. The sum will be:

$$\sum M_x=M_A-M_F+M_{BC}=0\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad\\ 
\sum M_x=M_A+159\;\mathrm{Nm}=0\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad\\ 
M_A=-159\;\mathrm{Nm}$$

Comment: You're absolutely right! Now I get it! Yes, the bearing at A produces a torque around x-axis as it restricts rotation around the axis and keeps the bar fixed. Thank you!